# Wildfly 8.1 Log System

Tags: log4j, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am trying to make my Web Services Application Log using Wildfly 8.1 Final Log System Categories.

My App declares

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("myapp");
```

It calls in parts of the code for

```
LOGGER.debug("something");
```

Using the log4j property file definition below it behaves as expected.   The problem is when I access the Wildfly console (http://localhost:9990/console/App.html#logging) and update the Log Category named "myapp" from INFO to DEBUG.  After tha I call my Web Service that calls the instruction LOGGER.debug("something"); inside it´s code.

The expected behavior is to show the "something" message written in my log file, but it does not happens because it behaves obeying only the log4j property file supplied below.

How to fix this?

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, stdout, myapp
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO, stdout, myapp
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=ALL, stdout, myapp
log4j.logger.myappaudit=INFO, myappaudit
log4j.logger.myapp=INFO, stdout, myapp
log4j.logger.performance=INFO, myapp

#
#  default Appender 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1} [%p] %C{1}.%M - %m%n

#
#  Appender for myappaudit
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
log4j.appender.myappaudit = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myappaudit.File = ${jboss.server.log.dir}/logs/myappaudit.log
log4j.appender.myappaudit.Append = true
log4j.appender.myappaudit.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.myappaudit.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myappaudit.layout.ConversionPattern =  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

#
#  Appender for application
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
log4j.appender.myapp = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myapp.File = ${jboss.server.log.dir}/logs/console.log
log4j.appender.myapp.Append = true
log4j.appender.myapp.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.myapp.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myapp.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

#Spring logs
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws=DEBUG

#Spring Transaction Logs
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG

#Spring Async Logs
log4j.logger.org.springframework.scheduling=ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to use the logger options in the console. The reason is that if you include a log4j config an entirely isolated logging instance is created for that deployment. If you want to use jboss's tools, you must remove your logging config and define in the standalone or domain xml. Alternatively, you can create your own servlet or mbean that is part of your deployment to make runtime adjustments to the logging level or any other changes, e.g adding or removing appenders

Comment: Is it enought to remove the log4j.properties only?  Or should I change the Logger defninition as well?

Comment: The presence of the file is what triggers the creation of the logger, so remove the file totally or if only for development, add the jboss system property to disable per deployment logging

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.  If understood, when I remove the log4.jproperties and maintain the private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("myapp"); declaration where Logger is a class from Log4J the wildfly will understand that it should be logged in jboss logging system and "myapp" willbe understood as a category and I will be able to observe the expected behaviour described on the post.  Is that it?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I would expect

Answer (score 0):

So, to be clear, are you packaging a log4j.properties file with your application? It that being respected correctly, but you hoped to use the jboss console to amend the logging level at runtime?

Comment: Yes, I am packing it within my war file inside ./src/main/resources and I was hoping to be able to use wildly console to switch log level for myapp category in order to debug.